# OpenMP parallel for cout order

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm quite new to openmp and encounter such question.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if (i == 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; ++j);   // Create a delay for i = 0.
    cout << i << flush;
}
```

I expected `0` should be the last integer printed out since there's a delay. However, the actual output is in total random order.

Is this caused by some kind of compiler optimization? Or do I misunderstood `parallel for`?

I have version

```
#define _OPENMP 201307
```

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from anything else, the compiler may well have optimised that "delay" away. If you want a proper delay use something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: Also the code seems to add the supposedly delay for i == 0 and not i == 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more likely you're misunderstood `parallel for`.

In most case when you don't set `schedule` for `omp for`,
every thread will execute one of loops.

so 1 is executed almost the same time with 0.

if you want 1 be executed after 0. try add `schedule(static, 2)`.

Comment: I've been developing openmp application for over 5 years. but I'm quite a new guy on answering question here. If I'm not giving what you want explicitly, pls comment.